# Converting correctly between tz unaware time, UTC and working with timezones in python

Tags: python, pytz

I have a string in the form '20111014T090000' with associated timezone ID (TZID=America/Los_Angeles) and I want
to convert this to UTC time in seconds with the appropriate offset.

The problem seems to that my output time is off by 1 hour (it's in PST when it should be PDT) and I'm using the pytz to help with timezo

```
import pytz

def convert_to_utc(date_time)
    # date_time set to '2011-10-14 09:00:00' and is initially unaware of timezone information

    timezone_id = 'America/Los_Angeles'
    tz = pytz.timezone(timezone_id);

    # attach the timezone
    date_time = date_time.replace(tzinfo=tz);

    print("replaced: %s" % date_time);                                                                          
    # this makes date_time to be: 2011-10-14 09:00:00-08:00
    # even though the offset should be -7 at the present time

    print("tzname: %s" % date_time.tzname());
    # tzname reports PST when it should be PDT

    print("timetz: %s" % date_time.timetz());
    # timetz: 09:00:00-08:00 - expecting offset -7

    date_time_ms = int(time.mktime(date_time.utctimetuple())); 
    # returns '1318611600' which is 
    # GMT: Fri, 14 Oct 2011 17:00:00 GMT
    # Local: Fri Oct 14 2011 10:00:00 GMT-7

    # when expecting: '1318608000' seconds, which is
    # GMT: Fri, 14 Oct 2011 16:00:00 GMT
    # Local: Fri Oct 14 2011 9:00:00 GMT-7 -- expected value
```

How do I get the correct offset based on the timezone Id?

Comment: You need a call to `date_time.localize`.  That's the only essential ingredient that is completely missing here.

Answer (score 3):

The following snippet will do what you wish

```
def convert(dte, fromZone, toZone):
    fromZone, toZone = pytz.timezone(fromZone), pytz.timezone(toZone)
    return fromZone.localize(dte, is_dst=True).astimezone(toZone)
```

The crucial part here is to pass `is_dst` to the localize method.

Comment: Based on the docs, it seemed that the is_dst flag may not interpret and provide the expected value: >>> dt = datetime(2002, 10, 27, 1, 30, 0)
>>> dt1 = eastern.localize(dt, is_dst=True)
>>> dt1.strftime(fmt)
'2002-10-27 01:30:00 EDT-0400'
>>> dt2 = eastern.localize(dt, is_dst=False)
>>> dt2.strftime(fmt)
'2002-10-27 01:30:00 EST-0500'

Comment: The `is_dst` argument is optional except in the case of an ambiguous time (i.e. during a "fall back" where the same hour of the day occurs twice in the local time zone).  The rest of the time the conversion will work without it.  The argument tells `pytz` whether daylight savings is in effect or not for the `datetime` object you supply.

Answer (score 0):

[simple-date](https://github.com/andrewcooke/simple-date) was written to make conversions like this trivial (you need version 0.2.1 or later for this):

```
>>> from simpledate import *
>>> SimpleDate('20111014T090000', tz='America/Los_Angeles').timestamp
1318608000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If changing the global time zone in your program is (temporarily) allowed, you can also do this:

```
os.environ['TZ'] = 'America/Los_Angeles'
t = [2011, 10, 14, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1]
return time.mktime(time.struct_time(t))
```

The expected 1318608000.0 is returned.

Answer (score 0):

To convert given string to a naive datetime object:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> naive_dt = datetime.strptime('20111014T090000', '%Y%m%dT%H%M%S')
>>> naive_dt
datetime.datetime(2011, 10, 14, 9, 0)
```

To attach the timezone (make it an aware datetime object):

```
>>> import pytz
>>> tz = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
>>> local_dt = tz.localize(naive_dt, is_dst=None)
>>> print(local_dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"))
2011-10-14 09:00:00 PDT-0700
```

Note: `is_dst=None` is used to raise an exception for non-existing or ambiguous local times.

To get POSIX timestamp from an aware datetime object:

```
>>> (local_dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)).total_seconds()
1318608000.0
```

The main issues in your question are:

1. You replace `tzinfo` attribute, `tz.localize` should be used instead
2. `mktime()` works with local time (your computer timezone), not UTC.